# Enabled Level FINE logger GeoTools/GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotools, logging

I would like to enable my logger in level FINE with GeoTools.

I changed my DEFAULT_LOGGING.properties to :

```
log4j.category.org.geotools=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.geotools.factory=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.geoserver=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.vfny.geoserver=DEBUG
```

But still when I debug geotools lib, `LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE)` always return false and I don't know, why ?

Comment: are you sure those are the packages you are interested in?

Comment: I see what you meant I added the name of the packages I was interested in :log4j.category.org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.geotools.imageio.netcdf=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.crs=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.cf=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.tools=DEBUG but nothing changed.

Comment: is this for a plain GeoTools program or GeoServer? if GeoServer just select GEOTOOLS-DEBUG in logging options. If GeoTools I nearly always end up editing the `jre/logging.properties` file

Comment: thank you for the response. Its GeoTools program I edit `jre/logging.properties` like org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.crs = FINE and I even change .level= FINE and java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE but nothing changed.

Comment: ## ALL                   FINEST
## TRACE                 FINER
## DEBUG                 FINE (includes CONFIG)
## INFO                  INFO
## WARN/ERROR            WARNING
## FATAL                 SEVERE
## OFF                   OFF

Comment: Ok I got what you mean. I changed all FINE by DEBUG but still no change. I make sure its the right logging.properties with $whereis java. It's `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/conf/logging.properties`

Comment: Did you change the `.level` at the top **and** the `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level` lower down?

Comment: Yes I changed it to DEBUG but `LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE)` still return false. I also change my log level in tomcat conf but nothing changed. The jars I want to change log level are in my geoserver project in the Web app libraries.